# I am trying to get the files in zip format which were newly created around two days ago using powershell and I am not getting any output

Tags: powershell

```
$Servers = Get-content 'D:\utils\Backup\SBX servers.txt'

foreach($Path in $Servers){
  $Path = "E:\Backup" 
  $result = Get-ChildItem E:\Backup\*_DB.zip -Recurse -Force -File |Format-Wide| Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-1)}
  $result
}
```

Comment: `foreach($Path in $Servers)`, followed immediately with `$Path = "E:\Backup"` and never actually using `$Path` looks unusual. Is that a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were not far from the solution, but there are multiple problem with your syntax. First you should not "filter" (where-object), after "formating" (Format-wide).

```
foreach($Path in $Servers){
    $Path = "E:\Backup"
    $result = Get-ChildItem E:\Backup*DB.zip -Recurse -Force -File | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-1)}
    $result | Format-Wide
}
```

you were missing the "underscore" in your filter too: "$." -> "$_."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and Format-Wide doesnt seem to work in this case. Could you suggest an alternative where i get the details of only the file ?

Comment: sorry i'm not sure of what you want to acheive, but you would remove the format-wide, alors do a $result | select *, this will display all properties for what's inside the result var.
personnaly i would not use the $result var, and directly do the Get-childitem | where-object .. | select *

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Since this is my first time scripting in powershell I am finding this hard